# Is there a way I can replace/remove everything in a string except for certain phrases?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I had a string and a list like this:

```py
myString = "This is a string which has stuff in it."
myList = ["string", "things", "python"]
```

Is there a way I can remove everything in myString except for the things that are listed in myList (in this case everything is removed except the word 'string')? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are partial matches allowed?

Comment: `print(" ".join(i for i in myString.split() if i in myList))` ?

Comment: `print([x for x in myList if x in myString])`?

Comment: @Rakesh It worked perfectly, thank you. That's so much easier than all the stuff I was trying to do.

Comment: @Rakesh As a side note, IIRC it's faster if you pass a list to `join` than a generator, i.e. using a list comprehension would be faster.

Comment: @Rakesh menthod will not work for 
myString = "This is a string which has stuff in it."
myList = ["string", "things", "python","it"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myString = "This is a string which has stuff in it."
myList = ["string", "things", "python", "it"]

print([x for x in myList if x in myString])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['string', 'it']
```

Comment: you need to make inverse of your output. OP is asking for words from list, not everything else.

Comment: Edited, and fixed the output as well, downvoters? 8-)

Comment: Not my downvote, I only pointed your mistake. But here, have an upvote for a "pythonic" solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
myString = "This is a string which has stuff in it."
myList = ["string", "things", "python","it"]
print(" ".join(word for word in re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  myString).split() if word in myList))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mytxt = "some sentence to ignore phase and carry on"
reg = re.compile(r"(ignore phase)")
final_str = re.sub(reg,'',mytxt)
print(final_str)
```

Output -

> some word to  and carry on